# Defining floats and proofs using flocq

Tags: floating-point, coq

I'm trying to figure out how to use the **flocq** package.  Below I have a simple script where I created a simple function.  However I can't figure out how to create two *binary32*'s that I can use to evaluate this function.  I get stuck on how to create the proof of "bounded".  I'd also like to be able to prove that, for example, for a particular x and y I won't get a *NaN*.  Is this the sort of thing that **flocq** is good for?  Or might there be another package I should look into?  Any help is appreciated!

```
Require Import Psatz.
From Flocq Require Import Fcore_FTZ Fcore Fcalc_ops Fappli_IEEE Fappli_IEEE_bits.

Definition b32_my_fun (x y : binary32) : binary32 :=
  b32_div mode_NE (b32_plus mode_NE x y) y.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cobbled this answer together by exploring the copy of flocq that is included in CompCert. You may be interested in looking at CompCert's `lib/Floats.v` and especially `lib/Fappli_IEEE_extra.v` which layer some convenience functions on top of flocq. (This also means that my answer *might* not be applicable to vanilla flocq, but I think it should.)

To create a `binary32`, use flocq's `binary_normalize` function from `Fappli_IEEE`. Here is its type:

```
binary_normalize
     : forall prec emax : Z,
       Prec_gt_0 prec -> prec < emax -> mode -> Z -> Z -> bool -> binary_float prec emax
```

For a 32-bit IEEE float, `prec` is 24 (bits of precision in the mantissa) and `emax` is 128 (the maximal value of the exponent). The `mode` argument is the rounding mode, `mode_NE` should be a reasonable choice. The two `Z` arguments are the values of the mantissa and the exponent, respectively; the final bool appears to be the sign to use if the mantissa is 0.

So for a 32-bit float with mantissa 42 and exponent 32, we can try the following:

```
Check (binary_normalize 24 128 _ _ mode_NE 42 23 false).
binary_normalize 24 128 ?prec_gt_0_ ?Hmax mode_NE 42 23 false
     : binary_float 24 128
where
?prec_gt_0_ : [ |- Prec_gt_0 24] 
?Hmax : [ |- 24 < 128]
```

It remains to provide proofs of two simple goals: `Prec_gt_0 24` and `24 < 128`. In interactive mode, both of these can be proved simply by `reflexivity`:

```
Goal Prec_gt_0 24.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The proof term for such proofs is simply `eq_refl` (as you can check with `Show Proof.` before the `Qed.`, for example). So we arrive at:

```
Check (binary_normalize 24 128 eq_refl eq_refl mode_NE 42 23 false).
binary_normalize 24 128 eq_refl eq_refl mode_NE 42 23 false
     : binary_float 24 128
```

And we can look at the real internal representation of this:

```
Eval simpl in (binary_normalize 24 128 eq_refl eq_refl mode_NE 42 23 false).
     = B754_finite 24 128 false 11010048 (FLT_exp (-149) 24 29)
         (proj1 (binary_round_correct 24 128 eq_refl eq_refl mode_NE false 42 23))
     : binary_float 24 128

Eval compute in (binary_normalize 24 128 eq_refl eq_refl mode_NE 42 23 false).
     = B754_finite 24 128 false 11010048 5
         (proj1 (binary_round_correct 24 128 eq_refl eq_refl mode_NE false 42 23))
     : binary_float 24 128
```

And finally we can package this in a nice little function:

```
Definition my_binary32 (mantissa exponent: Z): binary32 :=
  binary_normalize 24 128 eq_refl eq_refl mode_NE mantissa exponent false.
```

And test it:

```
Eval simpl in (my_binary32 42 23).
     = B754_finite 24 128 false 11010048 (FLT_exp (-149) 24 29)
         (proj1 (binary_round_correct 24 128 eq_refl eq_refl mode_NE false 42 23))
     : binary32

Eval simpl in (my_binary32 42 230).
     = B754_infinity 24 128 false
     : binary32
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  And thanks for the trick related to finding the proof term `eq_refl`, and the fancy `where` clause!